# MVC3 and JQuery table row cloning best practice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

What are your best practice rules when using MVC3 and iterating over a collection to display rows in a table as well as allow client side row additions using JQuery and/or Ajax? What I want to avoid is copying the table row markup and maintaining that in my JS code. I apologize if this has been covered already.

Here is what I want to avoid ..

Code for MVC View with a strongly typed Customer object

```
<table id="tblCustomers">
<tbody>
@foreach (Customer cust in Model)
{
    <tr><td><div class="nameholder">@cust.Name</div></td><td><div class="idholder">@cust.Id</div></td></tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" style="width:150px;" />
<input type="button" id="btnTest" value="Testing!" />
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnTest").click(function () {
        $("#tblCustomers").append('<tr><td><div class="nameholder">UiInputValue</div></td><td><div class="idholder">UiInputValue</div></td></tr>');

    });
});
```

I have seen code that suggest that cloning the last row in the table then changing the values is a way to go as with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnTest").click(function () {
        var clone1 = $("#tblCustomers tbody>tr:first").clone(true);
        var name = $("#txtName").val();
        $(clone1).find(".nameholder").html(name);
        $(clone1).find(".idholder").html('not yet defined');
        $("#tblCustomers").append(clone1);

    });
});
```

But the problem I see with that is in the case where the collection is empty and I need to be able to add the first row. I suppose you could have a hidden row to handle for that case but then that's just duplicated code.

Is there a best practices approach to cloning a HTML chunk that will remain consistent between both the View and in the JS? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I have used the "hidden row" method with good success. I have also used the [Jquery template library](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) for updating grids with AJAX which works great, albeit a bit fiddly

Comment: I also tried the approach of using a partial for just the row, displaying it for each record and also at the bottom of the view passing a new() and wrapped inside a named div. I then applied the clone() to the named div in hopes of getting the <tr><td> row tags but after the clone only the div's (inside the <td> tags) were returned from the clone so when adding it to the table it didn't show up. This would have seemed like a nice approach to the problem but without the <tr> and <td> tags is unusable.